# Can i set the font size and style of rich text editor(its inside a custom form)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I have a rich text box field in a custom form i built.
Right now users type in whatever they want but they want.But they don't want to be selecting the content manually to set a font and size.Is it possible to set the box to use e.g Arial and size 4 for example not matter what they add?

I have tried adding this to my masterpage but no luck as yet.I need this in a Listview.
I can see the text change to red but the font not changing

```
<style type="text/css">
     .ms-rtestate-field div

{

font-size:2px !important;
font-family:"Myriad Pro"!important;
color:red !important;

}
</style>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you trying to change the style of a rich text editor or the value of a rich text field in the column of a list view?

Comment: Thanks Rob.Sorry for the confusion.How can I set the default font and style of a multiple lines of text(rich text) box?
So when users view an item it is automatically set to this font and style.Do you get me?